# Worauf beziehen wir uns im Deutschen eigentlich heutzutage, wenn wir sprachliche Konstrukte "richtig" oder "falsch" nennen?

Tags: spelling, duden, rules

**Früher** war es der **Duden**, der "maßgebend in allen Zweifelsfällen" war, seit der Reform 1996 gibt es diesen Sonderstatus nicht mehr, und das Bundesverfassungsgericht urteilte zudem, "dass die amtliche Rechtschreibung nur für begrenzte Teile der Schriftproduktion bindend ist, während im Übrigen ein jeder nach eigenem Gutdünken schreiben darf, auch nach frei erfundenen oder veralteten Regeln." ([Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duden))

**Inzwischen** gibt es das "**amtliche Regelwerk" vom Februar 2006**, und das "regelt die Rechtschreibung innerhalb derjenigen Institutionen (Schule, Verwaltung), für die der Staat Regelungskompetenz hinsichtlich der Rechtschreibung hat." Darüber hinaus hat es lediglich "Vorbildcharakter für alle, die sich an einer allgemein gültigen Rechtschreibung orientieren möchten (das heißt Firmen, speziell Druckereien, Verlage, Redaktionen – aber auch Privatpersonen)."

Heißt das übersetzt "rechtlich können alle machen, was sie wollen, solange es nicht in einer öffentlichen Institution passiert"?

Denkt man darüber nach, stellt man fest, dass eigentlich auch früher weder Privatpersonen noch Zeitungen je für falsche Rechtschreibung bestraft wurden. Wozu dient dann das Urteil des Verfassungsgerichts? Waren Fehler früher illegal und sind jetzt rechtlich unbedenklich?

Comment: Du verlinkst doch selbst zu Wikipedia, die zum Urteil des Gerichts verlinkt. Wieso liest Du da nicht selbst nach, in welcher Sache das Gericht dort geurteilt hat? Sollen wir das Urteil vorlesen?

Comment: @user unknwon: lieber wäre mir eine Erklärung der dahinter steckenden Logik.

Comment: Wer ist 'wir'? Es ist beim lesen des Textes klar das Du Deutschland meinst, denke aber waere gut das im Titel entsprechend klarzustellen, da die Frage stark auf Deutschland ausgerichtet ist.

Comment: @inflagranti: Habe ich gemacht...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die Frage ist doch eher, wozu gibt es einheitliche Rechtschreibregeln? Viele Leute, heutzutage wie früher, sind der Meinung, dass Sprache sich sowieso weiterentwickelt und es deshalb egal ist, wie man etwas schreibt, solange man versteht, was gemeint ist. Genau an dieser Stelle entsteht jedoch das Problem: Woran erkennt man, was gemeint ist?

Natürlich entsteht durch Fehler häufig nur eine Unschönheit, die die Bedeutung eines Wortes oder Satzes nicht ändert. In manchen Fällen ändert sich aber schon durch eine kleine Unachtsamkeit die Bedeutung drastisch; sobald es also darauf ankommt, dass kein Irrtum geschieht, ist deshalb eine nach einem bestimmten Regelwerk korrekte Rechtschreibung erforderlich. Auf die Spitze treiben das daher Gesetzestexte und juristisch relevante Texte wie Verträge, die in vielen Fällen "normale" (zumeist einfache, alltägliche, daher aber auch oft mehrdeutige) Wörter vermeiden und sich penibel an die Regeln halten. Auch hier sind Fehler nicht illegal, dennoch können Fehler einen teuer zu stehen kommen, weil möglicherweise die Eindeutigkeit nicht mehr gegeben ist und ein Gericht daher im Zweifel entgegen der ursprünglichen Intention entscheiden könnte.

In Deutschland gilt die Amtssprache Deutsch; im Zweifel muss ein Text daher der amtlichen Rechtschreibung entsprechen, um im Falle eines Falles Bestand zu haben. Die Frage der Korrektheit bezieht sich daher immer auf diese Regeln. Es ist auch hilfreich für die allgemeine Verständigung, für Medien, die deutschlandweit bzw. im gesamten deutschsprachigen Raum) eingesetzt werden (Zeitungen, Bücher, Webseiten...), wenn 1. jeder Texte dafür verfassen kann und 2. jeder diese Texte lesen und verstehen kann. Auch wenn man dann Schülern Lesen und Schreiben beibringen soll, ist es hilfreich, wenn es nicht viele verschiedene Varianten gibt. Sobald es so etwas wie einen deutschen Staat gab, hat man daher versucht, die Regeln zu vereinheitlichen. Davon zeugen unter anderem die erste und die zweite ortographische Konferenz, die den Sinn hatte, die Rechtschreibung im kurz zuvor (1871) entstandenen deutschen Reich zu vereinheitlichen.

Die Rechtschreibung war lange Zeit unter der Aufsicht des Duden-Verlags, der eine Art Vollmacht für die Definition der deutschen Sprache hatte. 1996 wurde jedoch entschieden, dass so etwas nicht in die Hand eines privaten Verlags, sondern doch besser in die einer staatlichen (oder vielmehr staatsübergreifenden) Institution gehört, so dass man den Rechtschreibrat gegründet hat. Dieser schreibt die amtlichen Regeln vor, geht jedoch in einigen Punkten nicht ins letzte Detail. Meines Wissens gibt er auch amtliche Wortlisten heraus, die jedoch insbesondere der schnell anwachsenden Zahl von modernen Wörtern nicht gerecht werden. Der Duden-Verlag, ebenso wie viele andere Wörterbuchverlage, stellt im Wesentlichen eine ausführliche Liste aller Wörter mit deren Schreibung sowie eine "verständlichere" (weniger amtsdeutsche) Interpretation der Regeln bereit und bildet darüber hinaus eine Art Bestandsaufnahme von Wörtern ab, die heutzutage verwendet werden. Aus dieser Funktion der Vergangenheit heraus genießt der Duden immer noch ein recht hohes Ansehen, wenn es um Rechtschreibfragen geht, insbesondere seit er dazu übergegangen ist, auch viele umgangssprachliche oder technische Ausdrücke aufzunehmen.

Letztendlich kann jeder also schreiben, wie er will, sofern er keinen Text verfasst, der juristisch relevant ist (und auch dann ist es "sein Pech", wenn er falsch schreibt, und nicht strafbar). Es gilt jedoch als Zeichen von Bildung, sich an die amtlichen Regeln zu halten, und es erleichtert jedermann das Verständnis des geschriebenen Wortes. Oftmals ist dabei auch weniger die Frage von Richtig oder Falsch zu bewerten als vielmehr die Frage, ob etwas guter oder schlechter Stil ist.

---

Das Bundesverfassungsgericht bietet übrigens in seiner [Urteilsbegründung](http://www.bverfg.de/entscheidungen/rs19980714_1bvr164097.html) in der Tat eine hervorragende Zusammenfassung der Entwicklung der deutschen Schriftsprache.

Comment: Zu Abs. 2: "Auf die Spitze treiben das daher Gesetzestexte ..." - dem widerspreche ich. Gesetze werden von Parlamentariern gemacht, (teils gar von Lobbygruppen,) die in der politischen Debatte oft ihre Absichten vernebeln, und daher auch bei der Abfassung der Gesetze keine klare Sprache finden. Beispiel hierfür ist eine Regelung zur Verbreitung von digitalen Werken, an denen man keine Verwertungsrechte besitzt, wo es lt. Gesetz darauf ankommt, ob dies in `gewerblichem Ausmaß` geschieht. `Ausmaß` beschreibt m.E. eine Quantität, `gewerblich` aber eine Qualität. Hier hapert es m.E. am Grundsätzl.

Comment: @user unknown: Das fällt aber oft genug auf die Parlamentarier zurück. Wenn die Sprache ungenau ist, kann später ein Gericht auch anders entscheiden, und das passiert ja auch häufig. "Gewerbliches Ausmaß" finde ich hingegen ein schlechtes Beispiel. Einerseits ist hier die Formulierung bewusst schwammig (ein Gericht kann daher leicht von Fall zu Fall entscheiden und muss sich nicht an willkürlich festgelegte Zahlen halten), andererseits finde ich es relativ klar, was gemeint ist: ein gewerbliches Ausmaß ist sicherlich deutlich größer als ein privates (vgl. Privatkopie vs. gewerbliche Kopie).

Answer (score 1):

Eine ideale Schreibung wird über soziale Kontrolle mehr oder weniger sanktioniert, auch wenn dies nicht über den Gesetzgeber läuft.

Wenn sich 3 von 5 Kunden im Restaurant beschweren, dass der Kaffee Togo aus Guatemala kommt, und nicht aus Togo, dann wird der Wirt, um die nutzlosen Diskussionen zu vermeiden vielleicht die Karte neu drucken lassen.

Die Sprache soll generell leicht zu lesen sein - nicht unbedingt leicht zu schreiben, denn geschriebenes wird oft von mehr als einer Person gelesen, oder mehr als 1x gelesen. Daher ist es sinnvoll die Arbeit in die Produktion zu stecken, und nicht in den Konsum, und es ist Aufgabe der Sprachforscher die Regeln, die eine einfache Verständigung gewährleisten, zu finden, aufzuschreiben und zu kanonisieren.

Wenn heute "hervor stechende Merkmale" einer Pflanze nicht die Dornen einer Kaktee sind (die bei einer Kaktee gar nicht 'Dornen' heißen, sondern ... (- vergessen)), dann ist das m.E. eine Fehlentwicklung, die das Verstehen des Textes eben nicht befördert, und da ich kein Schüler bin werde ich den Teufel tun, und getrennt schreiben, was zusammen geschrieben besser verständlich wäre (außer zu Demonstrationszwecken hier und heute).

Eine oberste Autorität gibt es für mich nicht, aber da viele Personen der Meinung sind, dass da ein Thron vakant sind, besteht Hoffnung, dass sich eine Organisation, Gruppe oder Person herausgefordert fühlt, den Anspruch auf diesen Thron durch überzeugende Leistungen anzumelden.

Wenn dann die, die sich darum kümmern übereinkommen, dass jmd. dieser Thron zusteht, dann wird es auch wieder eine - wenn auch inoffizielle - oberste Autorität geben.