# Wer bestimmt, welche Regeln in der deutschen Sprache gelten?

Tags: spelling, standard-german, sociolinguistics, rules

Wie der Titel schon sagt: Wer (oder was) hat das letzte Wort, wenn es um Regelfragen in der deutschen Sprache geht?

Die angesprochenen Regelfragen können sowohl die Grammatik als auch die Rechtschreibung betreffen.

Comment: Wie ist die Frage zu verstehen? Meinst du, wer die Rechtschreibreformen definiert? Oder welcher Quelle bezüglich orthographischen / grammatischen Fragen am zuverlässigsten ist?

Comment: @Peasant Mir geht es darum wer tatsächlich, wenn auch nur theoretisch, die Macht hat Entscheidungen zu fällen, was zulässig ist und was nicht.

Comment: Zwar gibt es eine Amtliche Rechtschreibung, aber die ist, wie der Name schon sagt, hauptsächlich für Ämter (und Schulen) bindend. Wenn du ein Buch oder für eine Zeitung schreibst, wird das letzte Wort beim Verlag liegen (Hausorthographie); wenn du als Angestellter etwas schreibst, kann dir dein Chef Vorgaben machen; wenn du im Selbstverlag publizierst, hast du die "Macht [..] Entscheidungen zu fällen, was zulässig ist und was nicht". Es ist nicht einklagbar, dass du dich an ein amtliches Regelwerk zu halten hast.

Comment: Wer bestimmt welche Regeln im Englischen gelten? Die Antwort ist, dem Grunde nach, vergleichbar.

Comment: Siehe auch: [Auf was beziehen wir uns im Deutschen eigentlich heutzutage, wenn wir sprachliche Konstrukte “richtig” oder “falsch” nennen?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2580/1859) · [Deutscher Wortschatz - Definition?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5650/1859).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bezüglich der **Rechtschreibung** für Schulen und Behörden sind die vom [Rat für Rechtschreibung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_f%C3%BCr_deutsche_Rechtschreibung) entwickelten Rechtschreibregeln gewissermaßen die letzte Instanz. Der Rat kann gewisse Kleinigkeiten eigenhändig entscheiden, untersteht aber letzten Endes der Kultusministerkonferenz bzw. den Landesregierungen, die auch größere Änderungen absegnen müssen.

Auch wenn diese Regeln nur für im geringen Rahmen direkt gelten, bestimmen sie de facto die Rechtschreibung in der überwiegenden Mehrheit aller lektorierten Medien und die meisten Sprecher¹ des Deutschen würden sie als die richtige Rechtschreibung ansehen (was nicht notwendigerweise heißt, dass sie sich durchgehend daran halten, oder eine gute Meinung davon haben).

Historisch hatte bis 1996 der Duden in Rechtschreibfragen das letzte Wort. Dies führt dazu, dass auch heute noch viele glauben, dass dies der Fall wäre, und den Duden auch als absolute Instanz in Fragen der Grammatik, Aussprache u. Ä. betrachten.

Was die **Grammatik** betrifft, gibt und gab es keine offizielle Instanz – außer vielleicht der deutschen Sprecherschaft¹. Bei Letzterer ergibt sich natürlich das Problem, dass sie alles andere als homogen ist. Zum Beispiel würden verschiedene Sprecher denselben Inhalt wie folgt wiedergeben:

> Er sagte, er geht Bahnhof.
>   Er sagte, er geht zum Bahnhof.
>   Er sagte, er gehe zum Bahnhof.

Allerdings würde wohl kaum jemand, der die erste Variante nutzte, behaupten, dass es sich dabei um korrektes oder gutes Deutsch handelt und nicht wenige sind auch in der Lage, zumindest die zweite Variante zu produzieren, wenn sie es wollen. Die Mehrheit aller Sprecher wird wohl die zweite Variante produzieren. Variante drei ist schließlich die, die die oberen zwei Prozent, was die Sprachgewandheit betrifft, überwiegend nutzen und die man in einem lektorierten Text und Grammatiken liest. Und die Mehrheit aller Sprecher würde diesen Instanzen in derartigen Fragen auch Autorität bescheinigen.

---

In jedem Fall würde ich sagen, dass Wörterbücher bzw. Grammatiken (insbesondere aus dem Duden-Verlag) von der Mehrheit der Sprecher als höchste Instanz in derartigen Fragen akzeptiert werden. Und letztlich ist es ja Akzeptanz, was eine Autorität zur Autorität macht (zumindest solange diese Autorität nicht mit weitläufigem Zwang agiert).

---

<sup>¹ Ich nutze *Sprecher* hier im allgemeineren Sinne, der alle Sprecher, Schreiber und sonstigen Teilhaber der deutschen Sprache einschließt.</sup>

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort. Ich habe aber noch eine Frage bezüglich der deutschen Grammatik und dem Schulsystem. Da, wie du sagtest, es keine höchste Instanz der Grammatik gibt, frage ich mich worauf sich Lehrer (und Schulen allgemein) berufen können wenn es um die Richtigkeit der Grammatik geht.

Comment: Ich bin kein Lehrer, sehe aber nicht, wieso das nicht ohne funktionieren könnte. Es ist ja nicht so, dass es große Unterschiede zwischen den existierenden Grammatiken gäbe und solche Fragen häufig aufkämen. Alle anderen Fächer – insbesondere Englisch – kommen ja auch ganz gut ohne eine absolute Referenz aus.

Comment: @Wrzkprmft Auch wenn mich diese Antwort jetzt nicht befriedigt, liegt das wohl eher an mir und ich werde woanders nochmal nachfragen müssen :D Danke nochmal für die genaue Antwort

Comment: @ThreeFx: Was fehlt denn zu Deiner Zufriedenheit?

Comment: Durch die Antworten ist bei mir die Frage nach der allgemeinen Akzeptanz der Regeln der Grammatik und Rechtschreibung aufgekommen und von wegen dass alle Schüler, wie es sie momentan überall gibt ihre Arbeiten nach nicht durchsichtigen Kriterien bewerten lassen, da es keine einheitliche Festlegung der Rechtschreibung gibt und Lehrer trotzdem, natürlich mit Akzeptanz der Schüler, Fehler in Arbeiten aufzeigen und bewerten. Daraus ergeben sich für mich mehrere Fragen, zum Beispiel woher diese Akzeptanz stammt oder ähnliches, was eindeutig nicht auf German Language Stack Exchange passt.

Comment: @ThreeFx: »da es keine einheitliche Festlegung der Rechtschreibung gibt« – gerade für Schulen gibt es die doch. Falls Du *Grammatik* statt *Rechtschreibung* schreiben wolltest: Bedenke, dass es diverse Schulfächer und auch Aspekte des Deutschunterrichts gibt, die deutlich anfälliger für Willkür durch Lehrer sind. Die Akzeptanz von Grammatiken als Autorität rührt wohl schon daher, dass sie mit demjenigen kompatibel sind, was die oberen zwei Prozent (in Bezug auf die Sprachgewandtheit) nutzen.

Comment: Du schreibst »die meisten Sprecher des Deutschen würden sie als die richtige Rechtschreibung ansehen«. Die »Sprecher« brauchen aber gar keine Rechtschreibung. Es sind die »Schreiber« die sie benötigen, nicht die Sprecher. Das ist insofern beachtenswert als es ja auch Unterschiede z.B. im Satzbau zwischen gesprochenem und geschriebenem Deutsch gibt, was du in deinem Beispiel vom zum-Bahnhof-Gehen ja auch anklingen hast lassen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich nutze hier *Sprecher* im allgemeineren Sinne von *Nutzer, Teilhaber, [Schreiber und Sprecher].*

Comment: Worauf stützt sich z.B. die Aussage, dass es für die Grammatik keine Instanz gibt?

Comment: @äüö: Darauf, dass ich mich intensiv mit dem Thema auseinandersetze und mir bisher niemand untergekommen ist, der (belegbar) von sich behauptet eine offizielle Instanz zu sein oder dass jemand anderes es sei.

Comment: "Allerdings würde wohl kaum jemand, der die erste Variante nutzte, behaupten, dass es sich dabei um korrektes oder gutes Deutsch handelt" -> Das möchte ich gerne glauben, bin mir allerdings nicht sicher. Ich bemerke an mir selbst immer wieder, wie schnell "Mikro-Dialekte", z.B. innerhalb von Unternehmen oder Schulklassen, in das eigene Fleisch und Blut übergehen. Mit der Zeit werden diese dialektischen Differenzen zur eigenen Natur. Klassisches Beispiel: "Ich geh' mal _nach_ [REWE|Spar|Kaiser's (sic)|Thomas|Bastian|Sibylle|...].". Klar, "Ich geh X" ist krasser; aber wenn man's 20 Jahre nutzt?

Answer (score 13):

Der Herausgeber entscheidet, was in seinem Haus gedruckt wird. Der Chefredakteur entscheidet, was ein Nachrichtensprecher zu sagen hat. Jeder Deutsche entscheidet (natürlich beeinflusst von seinem Umfeld), was er sagt. Jeder Hörer entscheidet eigenmächtig, welchen Gebrauch er anmahnt oder nicht.

Es gibt also so viele Autoritäten, wie es Sprechsituationen gibt, und keine von ihnen ist offiziell oder endgültig. Es gibt keine *Académie Française* in Deutschland, und selbst die Gesellschaft für Deutsche Sprache wird mindestens ebenso sehr belächelt wie anerkannt.

Der Duden-Redaktion wird allgemein mehr Autorität beigemessen als anderen vergleichbaren Stellen, aber auch sie hat keine Entscheidungsgewalt – und die ständigen Aktualisierungen in diesem Standardwerk folgen meistens lange nach dem tatsächlichen Sprachgebrauch; d. h., sie kodifiziert nur nachträglich als "korrekt", was schon vorher üblich war. Ziemlich anarchisch für uns Deutsche, was?

Answer (score 9):

Die deutsche Rechtschreibung ist nicht über ein Gesetz geregelt. Dennoch muss man sich auf eine einheitliche Regelung berufen können, die festlegt, wie die deutsche Sprache an Schulen unterrichtet wird, und wie amtliche Dokumente verfasst werden. Diese [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/regelwerk.html) werden von Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung erstellt und von der [Kultusministerkonferenz](http://www.kmk.org/) als **verbindlich** festgelegt.

> Der Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung ist ein zwischenstaatliches Gremium, das vonseiten der staatlichen Stellen damit betraut wurde, die Einheitlichkeit der Rechtschreibung im deutschen Sprachraum zu bewahren und die Rechtschreibung auf der Grundlage des orthografischen Regelwerks im unerlässlichen Umfang weiterzuentwickeln. Der Rat ist somit die maßgebende Instanz in Fragen der deutschen Rechtschreibung und veröffentlicht mit dem amtlichen Regelwerk das Referenzwerk für die deutsche Rechtschreibung.<sup>[Kultusministerkonferenz](http://www.kmk.org/presse-und-aktuelles/meldung/rechtschreibung-muss-weiterentwickelt-werden-sprache-ist-nicht-starr.html)</sup>

Es besteht nach wie vor außerhalb von Schule und öffentlicher Verwaltung kein Zwang, sich an diese Regeln zu halten. Dennoch haben sie sich nahezu überall durchgesetzt. Alle Wörterbücher werden nach diesen Regeln erstellt. Auch für Österreich und die Schweiz geltende geringfügig abweichende Regeln sind in diesen amtlichen Regeln festgelegt.

Comment: Das gibt nur die Situation in Deutschland wieder, nicht aber die Situation der Deutschen Sprache. Es gibt nämlich noch andere Staaten in denen Deutsch gesprochen wird. In Deutschland mag es zutreffen, dass es kein Gesetz zur Regelung der Rechtschreibung gibt. In Österreich sind aber die Lehrpläne für den Unterricht an Österreichs Schulen Anlagen des Bundeslehrer-Lehrverpflichtungsgesetzes. Daher haben auch die Lehrpläne Gesetzeskraft, und in diesen Lehrplänen ist mehrfach ausdrücklich der Gebrauch des Österreichischen Wörterbuches als Referenzwerk der deutschen Sprache vorgeschrieben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: [*"Der Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung ist ein zwischenstaatliches Gremium"*](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rat/) - dieser Rat versteht sich also auch für die Schweiz, **Österreich**, Liechtenstein, Bozen-Südtirol und Belgien zuständig. Ich vermute also, dass man auch in Österreich gerne auf seine Empfehlungen zurückgreift. Siehe hierzu die auch vom *Bundesministerin für Unterricht und kulturelle Angelegenheiten der Republik
Österreich* mitunterzeichnete [Wiener Erklärung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/wiener_erklaerung.pdf).

Comment: Ich stimme dir vollinhaltlich zu. Im Rat der deutschen Rechtschreibung sitzen 39 Personen, darunter 9 Österreicher. Dieser Rat publiziert Empfehlungen. Sie haben (zumindest in Österreich) dieselbe Gesetzeskraft wie EU-Richtlinien, nämlich gar keine. Erst durch das Übernehmen solcher Vorschläge ins ÖWB werden diese Empfehlungen für jenen Personenkreis verbindlich, die sich gemäß Gesetz oder Verordnung als ÖWB halten müssen: Bundesbeamte und Schüler an Schulen die dem Bund unterstehen. Alle anderen (Journalisten, Buchautoren usw.) dürfen schreiben wie sie wollen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: na, dann ist es bei Euch tupfengleich wie bei uns :)

Comment: Ich glaube nicht ganz, denn in Deutschland gibt es meines Wissens nichts was mit dem ÖWB gleichzusetzen ist. Die Duden-Redaktion druckt zwar auch ein Wörterbuch, das auf den Empfehlungen des Rates beruht, aber der Duden ist - ebenso wie die Empfehlungen des Rates - für jeden Deutschen Staatsbürger (auch für alle Beamte) völlig unverbindlich. Jeder Deutsche darf schreiben wie es ihm oder ihr gefällt. Das trifft auf österreichische Bundesbeamte nicht zu. Diese sind dazu verpflichtet die Vorgaben des amtlichen Österreichischen Wörterbuches zu befolgen.

Comment: Regeln für Schulen & Beamte legt in D die Kultusministerkonferenz fest. Dort werden Regeln und das Wörterverzeichnis des Rechtschreibrats übernommen. Ein extra Buch, das man **kaufen** muss, wird bei uns heute nicht mehr verlangt.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt ja nicht nur ein einziges Deutsch. Es gibt mehrere deutsche Sprachen (um genau zu sein: Varietäten der deutschen Sprache), und zu diesen gehören unterschiedliche Instanzen die das Regelwerk festlegen, weswegen diese Varietäten auch tatsächlich unterschiedliche Regeln haben.

Ein Beispiel: Der Satz »Ich habe den Schweinsbraten gesalzen« wäre in deutschem Deutsch falsch (es müsste »Schweinebraten« und »gesalzt« heißen), in österreichischem Deutsch aber völlig korrekt. Siehe auch den Wikipedia-Artikel [Österreichisches Deutsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_Deutsch)

Die oft gehörte Aussage der Duden wäre bis 1996 das allgemein verbindliche Regelwerk der Deutschen Sprache gewesen ist schlichtweg falsch. In Österreich hat der Duden niemals Gültigkeit gehabt.

Das amtliche Regelwerk für österreichisches Deutsch ist das Österreichische Wörterbuch (»ÖWB«). Jedes Jahr gibt jenes Ministerium, das für den Unterricht an Österreichs Schulen zuständig ist (derzeit das »Bundesministerium für Bildung und Frauen«, früher »Bundesministerium für Unterricht und Kunst«), dieses Wörterbuch heraus.

Das ÖWB ist für alle Schüler und für alle Bundesbeamten verbindlich und es gilt in Österreich und den deutschsprachigen Gebieten Italiens (Südtirol).

Das ÖWB orientiert sich natürlich am Rat der deutschen Rechtschreibung, dem ja auch neun Österreicher (und ein deutschsprachiger Italiener) angehören, aber die Empfehlungen des Rates sind für Österreichisches Deutsch nicht verbindlich. Sollte das ÖWB den Regeln des Rates widersprechen gilt in Österreich das was im ÖWB steht. (Und - wie schon erwähnt - das was im Duden steht war uns Österreichern immer schon egal).

Ich habe leider keine Ahnung, wie die Situation im Fall der dritten deutschen Standardvarietät, dem Schweizerischen Deutsch (das auch die Amtssprache Liechtensteins ist), geregelt ist. Ich habe aber großes Interesse das zu erfahren.

Comment: Auch in Deutschland gibt der Rat nur eine Empfehlung an das Kultusministerium, das danach die amtlichen Regeln herausgibt. Man wird sich aber vermutlich sowohl in Deutschland als auch in Österreich an diese Empfehlungen halten. Hast Du Beispiele für eine gegenüber den Empfehlungen anderslautende Regel im ÖWB? Das wäre das eigentlich Interessante!

Comment: Noch ein Hinweis: die Geschäftsführerin des Österreichischen Bundesverlags (Herausgeber des ÖWB), Frau Helga Haunschmied-Donhauser sitzt ebenfalls im Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung.

Comment: Nein, mir sind keine Abweichungen bekannt weil ich die Empfehlungen des Rates nicht kenne. Ich werde, wenn ich mal Zeit habe, aber diese Empfehlungen lesen und mit dem ÖWB vergleichen. Ich vermute aber, dass sich der Rat bei Fragen wie »winken - winkte - gewunken(Ö)/gewinkt(D)« entweder vornehm zurückhält oder das Wort »gewunken« als Austriazismus tituliert.

Comment: Ich denke, die sind alle dort eingepflegt: [Regionale und mundartliche Besonderheiten sind nicht erfasst. Länderspezifische
Wörter (Austriazismen und Helvetismen) werden jedoch
verzeichnet, sofern sie in Österreich beziehungsweise in der Schweiz
als standardsprachlich gelten. Sie sind, sofern es sich nicht um österreichische
oder schweizerische Schreibvarianten handelt, nicht markiert.](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf)

Comment: Na toll. Da wird so getan als gäbe es nur zwei Arten länderspezifischer Wörter, nämlich Austriazismen und Helvetismnen. Was ist mit Wörtern wie »Abitur«, »Grundschule«, »Bürgersteig«, »Vorfahrt« usw.? Das sind auch länderspezifische Wörter, aber weder Austriazismen noch Helvetismen, sondern eben Teutonismen, also Wörter die in Deutschland, aber eben nur dort und sonst nirgendwo, als standardsprachlich gelten. Da wird so getan als wäre das in Deutschland gesprochene Deutsch das »eigentliche« bzw. das »richtige« Deutsch und die anderen Varietäten dieser untergeordnet.

Comment: Das ist nicht richtig so. Niemeand behauptet, die Sprache, die in Deutschland gesprochen wird, sei die einzig richtige. Auch bei uns gibt es eine regional unterschiedliche Standardsprache. Das ÖWB schreibt: "Die Standardsprache (Hochsprache, Schriftsprache)
ist die in der Öffentlichkeit allgemein
gültige, offiziell anerkannte und weitgehend
genormte Sprachform. Sie wird **im ganzen
deutschen Sprachraum** verstanden und **angewandt.**". Das mag für *Matura*, *Volksschule*, *Gehsteig* und *Vorrang* genauso wenig sein, wie für *Fenstersims*, *Bühne*, und *Kandel*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: *gewunken* vs. *gewinkt* (sowie andere Vokabel bzw. Grammatikvarianten) haben nichts mit der Rechtschreibung zu tun, weswegen der Rechtschreibrat sich dazu nicht äußern wird. (Und ganz nebenbei ist *gewinkt* nach meiner Wahrnehmung auch in Deutschland ausgestorben.)