# Is it wrong not to use Konjunktiv I (K1) in indirect speech?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive

I increasingly see cases where Konjunktiv I is not used to mark indirect speech and the indicative present is used instead, e.g.:

> Er sagte, er muss nach Haus gehen.

instead of

> Er sagte, er müsse nach Haus gehen.

Since I heard examples like these from native German speakers, I’m starting to doubt what the real use of K1 is.
Would it be considered wrong using the indicative present instead of the K1 in the following cases?

- Informal speech
- Formal speech
- Informal letter/email
- Formal essay such as those at university, work and so on.

Comment: Just a note: I think that „Er hat gesagt, dass er nach Hause gehen muss.“ is even more commen.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I used that just to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indirect speech is by far the main use of the Konjunktiv I in German (the distant second being [recipe-like instructions](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1756/2594)) – so one could argue that if you do not use the Konjunktiv I here, do not bother learning it for active use at all. Using the Konjunktiv I for indirect speech in any situation will arguably understood by every native speaker and is certainly not wrong.

However, using the Indikativ instead is so common that the main reason to consider it wrong would be because the grammar book says so (see [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15246/2594) on what can be considered right and wrong in German grammar). So if you use the Indikativ for indirect speech at almost any occasion, most people won’t even notice.

Note that, in German, there is no special grammar for certain formality levels or types of communication¹. People are just less sloppy and language change arrives later in written communication, higher levels and formal occasions (as it probably is the case with every language).

---

<sup>¹ In constrast, e.g., to French (in particular regarding the subjonctif) – at least according to what I was taught in school.</sup>

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks, I was worried because my grammar book is strict about using it but I remember only few times when I heard it in oral speech..

Comment: There might be a subtle difference in understanding, when you are quoting someone's opinion. Using the Konjunktiv will clearly underline that you do not necessarily agree with that opinion. When using the Indikativ, you are implying that you are agreeing with the quoted opinion.
As said in this answer though, most people won't even notice the use of the Indikativ; but I think using the Konjunktiv might be widely noticed.

Comment: @Chips_100: Selbst wenn dem so wäre, würde das nur in längeren Texten desselben Autors funktionieren, da ich dann ja erstmal sicherstellen muss, dass dieser standardmäßig den Konjunktiv nutzt (oder nur Meinungen wiedergibt, die er teilt). So oder so habe ich das noch nie so verwendet oder in einer Grammatik festgehalten gesehen und es ist auch entgegen der normalen Funktion des Konjunktivs. (Es sei denn, der Unsinn von der Möglichkeitsform hat sich durch jahrzentelanges Lehren in Realität verwandelt.)

Comment: @Chips_100 I read something about this idea of a more "distant" speaker (from the one who spoke). Though I really am confused on this matter.. I guess reading more German (books, newspaper ecc) will help me figuring out the real use..

Answer (score 3):

In der normalen Umgangssprache wird bei indirekter Rede meist der Indikativ gebraucht. Der Konjunktiv wird in förmlicher geschriebener Sprache oder bei öffentlichen Reden gebraucht.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience `Er hat gesagt, dass er nach Hause gehen muss.` is a lot more common than `Er sagte, er muss nach Haus gehen.` and as a native speaker, I would always use the former.
More importantly, according to [Lehrerfreund](http://www.lehrerfreund.de/schule/1s/indirekte-rede-indikativ/2569) (as of 2006), using Indikativ in indirect speech is/was a valid option in German schools, whereas without the "dass" it is to be corrected and counted as an error.
Keep in mind that rules for exams as well as grammar rules change all the time, therefore the reference might be out of date.

Comment: Anhand des verlinkten Beitrags würde ich den *Lehrerfreund* als sehr unzuverlässige Quelle einstufen. Erstmal scheint er auch 2006 noch für *amtlich* zu halten, was die Duden-Redaktion von sich gibt – was für Grammatikfragen meine Wissens nach noch nie stimmte (und wenn es heute stimmen würde, würbe der Duden damit). Und dann wird der [zitierte Duden-Newsletter](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/duden-newsletter-vom-27-01-06) noch nicht einmal korrekt wiedergegeben. Der ganze zitierte Beitrag scheint also auf einem Missverständnis zu beruhen.

Comment: @Su-Au Hwang yes, I agree that the first form is more common, I used the example just to make my question clearer.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Die Regeln von dem Konjunktiv I sehen mir nicht so klar aus. Ich lerne Deutsch seit fast zwei Jahre in meiner Freizeit, aber ich habe den Konjunktiv I nur letzten Monat studiert und ich bin nicht sicher, wie er benutzt werden soll. Könnten Sie mir bitte empfehlen, wo man die offiziellen Regeln finden kann? Danke für ihre Hilfe.

Comment: @mickkk: Es gibt keine ”offiziellen“ Regeln der deutschen Grammatik. Es sollte aber Listen guter Grammatikseiten hier geben (auch wenn ich sie gerade nicht finden kann). Im Zweifelsfall stell auch ruhig eine neue Frage (über den Konjunktiv oder Grammatikseiten im Allgemeinen).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Schade, dass es keine "offiziellen" Regeln gibt. Ok, dann werde ich Im internet und StackExchange nach Grammatikseiten suchen und alles zusammenfassen um meine Kenntnisse der Deutschen Grammatik zu verberssern. Vielen dank!